# Using Eclipse on the Mac and the Alt Key in mappings

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, alt

One thing that has always frustrated me with using Eclipse on the Mac is the keyboard mappings that require the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> key.  I'm used to using Eclipse in a Linux environment, and using that key in the mappings isn't an issue.  However, on the Mac its purpose is for entering special characters.

Is there any way to switch this so that Eclipse's default key mappings work correctly?

I use commands like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and a few others quite frequently, and not being able to slows me down.  I also would like to use what I'm used to so that switching environments is a little more transparent.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Comment: In fact, the problem seems to be related to the commands I'm trying to bind, not the keys :-/

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong key combinations; anything that would use alt+shift on Linux uses alt+cmd on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Keys preference]

Is this what you're looking for?
To modify just go to "Binding:" and then press the hotkeys

Comment: No, but thanks for the help.  I was using the wrong key: should have been alt+cmd rather than alt+shift.